# Is there any unique Id that ag-grid generates and attaches for every row in the grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, angular-directive

I wanted to implement the validations of certain columns in the ag-grid table in angular. My approach towards it is,

1. I will maintain a form group and the children's of form groups are form arrays. The controls in the form array are pushed from a directive that sits on top of ag-grid.
2. I use a custom cell renderer to display a border around the cell to show case an error entry by the user.
3. So to get the correct control from form array inside the cell renderer component, I need to map a unique Id of row with the form array index to get the correct control.
4. I tried using RowNodeId but that Id currently is coming up from a backend system. When I copy a row, then that row doesn't have any Id, that creates a problem for me to fetch the correct control from form array.
5. While debugging I have found RowNode has "_objectId" associated with it, which seems unique and this will be available for copied rows also and I see it doesnt change with grouping/sorting/filtering.

Could anyone suggest me how should I decide my Id for the above mentioned scenario. I really appreciate for your help in advance.

PS: I am using v22 of ag-grid for some reason.

Comment: so [here you can see how objectId is generated](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/2b78b286e7bd1dd16f6901d2d24b8b78c0148c22/community-modules/core/src/ts/entities/rowNode.ts#L242-L242), it's a counter, so any new RowNode instance will get a new one. You could use for rowId one of the columns from the dataset that doesn't change on frontend, as in `getRowNodeId: (data) => data.employeeId,`. Or you could use controls index in formArray as an ID for a row.

Comment: Thanks for your response, The problem with using the getRowNodeId function is, we have a functionality in ag-grid which duplicates a row. when we duplicate, we are removing the unique Id, lets say as you mentioned "employeeId". I understand _objectId is always unique in ag-grid table as I looked into the git link.

Comment: yes, if you create a new row by duplicating, it should produce new incremental number as ID